# proof: when the dot product of a number of vectors and a specific vector is constant, those vectors are on the same line orthogonal to the vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

Assume that there are three dot products:

a.w = c

b.w = c

d.w = c

in which, a,b,d, and w are vectors and c is a number.

I read it in a book about neural networks(by Martin T. Hagan) that when the dot product of a group of vectors and weight vector(a specific vector,w) is constant, it means those vectors are on the same line and are orthogonal to the weight vector(w). I don't understand why? Also, if two vectors are orthogonal, isn't the dot product zero?(since the cosine of 90 is 0)

[refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKRpO.png)

Comment: Please specify what $A, B, C$ are and their dimensions. Are them matrices?

Comment: @VanBaffo i just edited my question. a,b,d, and w are all 2d vectors.

Comment: They are not necessarily all on the same line, but all on the same _hyperplane_. In $2$-dimensions this will indeed be a line, but in $n$-dimensions it will be something that is flat and $(n - 1)$-dimensional.

Comment: @JosephHarrison can you please provide the proof?

Comment: @mhd nickz I shall have a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, the points $p \in \mathbf{R}^n$ satisfying $p \cdot w = c$ for some fixed $w \in \mathbf{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbf{R}$ form an $(n - 1)$-dimensional *hyperplane*. For example when $n = 2$, this is a line and when $n = 3$ it is a plane. It seems that OP is referring to the two dimensional case. If $w = (u, v)$ and $p = (x, y)$ then
\begin{align}
p \cdot w = ux + vy = c
\end{align}
is the familiar equation of a line. If $v \neq 0$, then it is the line $y = -(u/v)x + c/v$ having slope $-(u/v)$ and intercept $c/v$. If $v = 0$, then it is the vertical line $x = c/u$.

Addition: You're correct that the vectors $a \in \mathbf{R}^n$ and $w$ are orthogonal if and only if $a \cdot w = 0$. The thing is that if $a \cdot w = c$ and $b \cdot w = c$, then
\begin{align*}
(a - b) \cdot w = c - c = 0.
\end{align*}
Remember that $a - b$ is the displacement vector from $b$ to $a$ and so it points in the direction of the line. Then we have shown that the direction of the line is orthogonal to $w$.

Comment: thank you so much for your clear explanation. while this proves that those vectors(points) are on the same line, it doesn't fully answer my question as to the reason why those vectors and w are orthogonal. any idea?

Comment: Oh yes, I shall update my answer

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me :)